# module 'skipthoughts' has no attribute 'load_model'

Tags: python

I was implementing the following text encoder code but was facing this error:

```
from codecs import EncodedFile
import os 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join 
import skipthoughts 
import os.path
import pickle
# from keras.models import load_model

annot_dir='annot/test_annotations'
encoded_vector_dir='annot/test_encoded'
garbage='annot/test_garbage'

model=skipthoughts.load_model()
ofiles=[f_ for f_ in listdir(annot_dir) if isfile(join(annot_dir,f_))]

ofiles_1=ofiles[0: len(ofiles)//5]
ofiles_2=ofiles[len(ofiles)//5: 2*len(ofiles)//5]
ofiles_3=ofiles[2*len(ofiles)//5: 3*len(ofiles)//5]
ofiles_4=ofiles[3*len(ofiles)//5: 4*len(ofiles)//5]
ofiles_5=ofiles[4*len(ofiles)//5: 5*len(ofiles)//5]


for files in ofiles:    
    if os.path.exists(join(encoded_vector_dir,files))==False :
        with open(join(annot_dir,files)) as f:
            captions=f.read().split(',')
        
        captions=[cap for cap in captions if len(cap.strip())>0]

        try:
            caption_vectors=skipthoughts.encode(model,captions)
        except:
            with open(join(garbage,files),mode='wb') as myfile:
                pickle.dump(caption_vectors,myfile)
    else:
        print('skipped')
```

and below is the error I'm facing, if anyone has a solution if might be very helpful. Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\encoder.py", line 14, in <module>
    model=skipthoughts.load_model()
AttributeError: module 'skipthoughts' has no attribute 'load_model'
```

Comment: [GitHub Issue: Facing An Issue When Trying to run command in iPython: model = skipthoughts.load_model()](https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts/issues/101)

Comment: You might be confusing 2 different packages [skipthoughts](https://pypi.org/project/skipthoughts/) vs. [skip-thoughts](https://pypi.org/project/skip-thoughts/)